# fetching images from firebase in swift 3

Tags: uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase as a backend for my project.I need to display text and image from Firebase database in tableview. It displays only text in my tableview and shows error while retrieving image as "cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'String'".Please anyone, who can correct me. My code is given below:

//App Delegate

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FIRApp.configure()

    return true
}
```

//View Controller

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference? = nil
var refHandle: UInt? = nil
var userList = [User]()



@IBOutlet var tblHome: UITableView!

let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tblHome.delegate = self
    tblHome.dataSource = self


   self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    print("ref = ",ref)
    fetchUsers()

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("userList is", userList.count)
    return userList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HomeCell


    cell.profname.text = userList[indexPath.row].imageName

  if let url = URL.init(string: userList[indexPath.row].imageUrl) {             // Error: cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'String'
        cell.profImage.image.downloadedFrom(url: url)
    }


    return cell

}



func fetchUsers() {

    refHandle = ref?.child("Users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        print("refHandle =", self.refHandle)

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            print("dictionary =", dictionary)
            let user = User()
            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            self.userList.append(user)

            print("userlist is", user)

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tblHome.reloadData()

            })

        }

    })

}



}

extension UIImageView {
func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    contentMode = mode
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data, error == nil,
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
            self.image = image
        }
        }.resume()
}
  //  func downloadedFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
     //   guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
   //     downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)
   // }
}
```

//Home Cell

```
import UIKit

class HomeCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var profImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var profname: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
}
```

//User

```
import UIKit


class User: NSObject {
var imageName: String?
var imageUrl: UIImage?
}
```

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: if let url = URL.init(string: userList[indexPath.row].imageUrl) {             // Error: cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'String'
        cell.profImage.image.downloadedFrom(url: url)
    }          This line in view controller is giving error. I have marked the cause for error also. @eshirima

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [`URL()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779737-init) takes a String and you are passing a [UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage) to it.

Inside your `User` class, `imageUrl` is of type `UIImage?` and you are passing it into the URL constructor even though it is expecting a String.

You can solve this by changing your `User` class to this:

```
class User: NSObject 
{
    var imageName: String?
    var imageUrl: String? // pass this to the URL constructor
    var image: UIImage? // this stores the actual image
}
```

Comment: Now, getting error at : if let url = URL.init(string: userList[indexPath.row].imageUrl!) {        //  cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'String'
            
           
            
           cell.profImage.image.downloadedFrom(url: url)
        }//Error: value of type 'UIImage?' has no member 'downloadedFrom'

Comment: Do u fully understand your code? Or did you get it from an online resource? I am asking this because your actual use is different from your setup in both occasions i.e. the `String` issue and the `downloadedFrom`

Comment: Sorry but I can't do that; away from my laptop. Change it to `cell.profImage.downloadedFrom(url: url)` instead. I would really advise against getting code from SO especially if u are not sure of what is going on or how to integrate it into your project. Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview) and [watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4uDbWj8qhs) to understand `UIImageViews` and how to use extensions respectively.

Comment: I got this solution from stack overflow only.. so i used it. I got problem at that only. It prints data on console. just i need to fetch data from extension.